# services on docker swarm are not whitelisted by atlas cluster that is peered with the vpc

Tags: mongodb, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

the overview of the environment:

1. Mongodb cluster on Atlas that is peered with the vpc
2. Ec2 instance running in the VPC
3. docker swarm inside the EC2 instance.

What am I experiencing:

1. I am able to connect to mongo using the mongo cli from the EC2 instance
2. all my containers aren't able to connect to the mongodb even though they are running on this EC2 instance
3. as soon as I whitelist the public ip of the EC2 instance they are able to connect - but this is weird, I want them to be able to connect because the instance they are running on is able to connect without any special whitelisting.

swarm initialisation command I used:

`docker swarm --init --advertise-addr <private ip of the EC2>`

It didn't work when i tried with the public ip and it also doesn't work when i am not adding the  `--advertise-addr` to the swarm init.

additional useful information:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine as builder

ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN npm i npm@latest -g
RUN mkdir /app && chown node:node /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ tini \
    && apk add --update tzdata

USER node
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean --force
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080


FROM builder as dev
USER node
CMD ["nodemon", "src/services/server/server.js"]

FROM builder as prod
USER node
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s CMD node healthcheck.js
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["node", "--max-old-space-size=2048" ,"src/services/server/server.js"]
```

I have no clue why it behaves like this, How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does atlas documentation state whitelisting is not needed with vpc peering?

Comment: And my guess is you are connecting to different things from instances and containers. Use URIs and use identical URIs.

Comment: vpc peering is for the entire VPC to be whitelisted by the atlas cluster. that is the whole idea. somehow it thinks that the container has a different private IP, or even doesn't have the same private IP as the EC2 instance it is running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a meeting with a senior DevOps engineer we finally found the problem.
turns out the CIDR block of the network that the containers were running in was overlapping with the CIDR of the VPC. what we did is add the following to the docker-compose

```
networks:
  wm-net:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16 #this CIDR doesn't overlap with the VPC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your swarm containers are running on a separate network on your EC2.

As explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/), a special 'ingress' network is created by docker when initializing a swarm.

In order to allow them to connect you may need to reconfigure the default settings set up by docker, or whitelist the specific network interface that is used by docker's ingress network.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? a step by step solution will be nice.

Comment: also, the docker network is running on the machine, so how come the atlas cluster doesn't recognise that the traffic is from a machine in the vpc ?